# Yii2 Order by calculated field

Tags: yii2

I have two tables:

**Orders:**

```
- id
- client
- ...
```

**Lines:**

```
- orderID
- startDate
- endDate
- ...
```

In my orders' Controller I added these two to get dates from each order lines:

```
    public function getStartDate()
    {   
        return OrdersLines::find()
        ->andWhere(['orderID'=>$this->id])
        ->min('startDate');
    }

    public function getEndDate()
    {        
        return OrdersLines::find()
        ->andWhere(['orderID'=>$this->id])
        ->max('endDate');
    }
```

In my Index view (using kartik's grid and expandRowColumn) I show the orders grid with 2 calculated columns:

> - start_Date: gets the sooner start date from lines for each order
> - end_Date: gets the higher end date from lines for each order

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'export' => false,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class'         => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                'value'         => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                },
                'detail'        => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    $searchModel = new OrdersLinesSearch();
                    $searchModel->orderID = $model->id;
                    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                    return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_ordersLines', [
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);
                },
            ],
            ...             
            [
                'attribute' => 'start_Date',
                'format' => 'date',
                'label' => 'Start Date',
                'value' => 'startDate',

            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'end_Date',
                'format' => 'date',
                'label' => 'End Date',
                'value' => 'endDate',
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

How can I set OrdersSearch model to allow sorting with these values (start_Date and end_Date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should create ActiveDataProvider using join in ActiveQuery, using sort parameter passed to action:

```
$sort = \Yii::$app->request->get('sort');

if($sort == 'startDate') $having = 'MAX(startDate)';
if($sort == 'endDate') $having = 'MAX(endDate)';

$sql = Orders::find()->joinWith(['lines' => function($q) use($having) {
     $q->having = $having;
}]);
```

Comment: thank you @fabrizio-caldarelli. Tried that as per below code, but when i click both on enddate or start date to sort the list it shows just one record instead of all records sorted by date:

$sort = \Yii::$app->request->get('sort');

  if (strpos($sort, 'start_Date') !== false) $having = 'MAX(startDate)';
  if (strpos($sort, 'end_Date') !== false) $having = 'MAX(endDate)';

if (isset($having)) {
    $query = Orders::find()->joinWith(['ordersLines' => function($q) use($having) {
      $q->having = $having;
    }]);
   }
   else $query = Orders::find();